# getData() is undefined! Trying to store a variable

Tags: javascript, storage

I'm making an announcements app for my school. So basically the teacher posts an announcement, and if the gender and grade of the announcement matches your gender and grade, then it will display. The problem I'm having right now is that the gender and grade you choose for yourself doesn't store and I keep getting a getData() is undefined, while I have identical code for the create announcement side, and it works perfectly fine.

```js
Settings.js

var userName;
var alert;
var getUser;

var filter = [];
var index = 0;

function getData() {
    'use strict';
    filter[index] = {
  gender2: $("#gender2").val(),
  grade2: $("#grade2").val()
 
 };
 index++;
    var string = JSON.stringify(filter);
    console.log(string);
    localStorage.setItem('filter', string);
}
```

```css
Settings.css

body {margin: 0;}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #3c948b;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size: 15px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
background-color: #202020;
}

ul.topnav ul.right {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav ul.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #3c948b;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #3c948b;
}

center 


/*nav{
    border:1px;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background: grey;
 margin-right: 1px;
    height: 50px;
}
nav li{
    display:inline;

}
nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
/*Hover state for top level links
li:hover a {
 background: #3c948b;
}
#ann {
 margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
Settings.html 

<!doctype html>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<html lang="en">
    <link href="Settings.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<head>
<body>
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="Main2.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <ul class="topnav right">
    <li><a href="Settings.html">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
      </head>
    <br>
<center>
  <div id="ann"></div>
 </center>
<center>
<div class="dropdown1">
    <select id = "gender2">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
   
 <div class="dropdown2">
    <select id = "grade2">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Grade</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
 <br>
 <input type="button" class="Save" *this is problems ->*onclick= "getData()" value="Save"></input>
 <br>
 <input type="button" href="HT.html" class="Log Out" onclick= "location.href='ht.html';" value="Log Out" ></input>
 </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
Teacher-Create.js

var userName;
var alert;
var getUser;

var announcement = [];
var index = 0;

function getData() {
    
    announcement[index] = {
  club: $("#Club").val(),
  announcement: $("#ann").val(),
  gender: $("#gender").val(),
  grade: $("#grade").val()
  
  
 
 };
 index ++;
    var string = JSON.stringify(announcement);
    console.log(string);
    localStorage.setItem('announcement', string);
}
```

```css
Teacher-Create.css

@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

#club {
text-align: center;
}

#ann {
text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 315px;
}

#Club {
text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 315px;
}


h5 {
margin: -1px;
font-size: 13px;
color: orange;
font-family: 'FontAwesome'
}

#view {
text-align: center;
}

.post {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.preview {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}

#ann {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2.5px;    
}

.box2 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.box3 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.grid {
  margin: 120px auto;
  max-width: 20rem;
  width: 90%;
}
#all {
   align-content: center;
}
```

```html
Teacher-Create.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Teacher-Create.css"/>
<head>
    <script src="Teacher-Create.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="grid">
        <input id="Club" class="all" type="text" class="Club" placeholder="Club" required/>
        <input id="ann" class="all" type="text" class="ann" placeholder="Announcement" required/>
 <center> 
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <select id = "gender">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
      <option value="Male & Female">Male & Female</option>
    </select>
   
 <div class="dropdown2">
    <select id = "grade">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Grade</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="Juniors">Juniors</option>
   <option value="Seniors">Seniors</option>
   <option value="All">All</option>
    </select>
 </center>
  
            <input type="button" class="preview" value="Preview"></input>

            <input type="button" class="post" onclick= "getData()" value="Post"></input>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getData()` method is defined in `Teacher-Create.js` file and you have not included that in your Settings.html, but still trying to call the method,

You need to include Teacher-Create.js script in your `Settings.html` file.

```
<head>
 <script src="Teacher-Create.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it still doesn't seem to store the info. I'm trying to store it in local storage and I linked it to my Settings.js and even teacher-create.js, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle of your issue ?